# Connection control in n-tier application

Tags: c#, n-tier-architecture

I’m new in N-tier application and I’m trying to understand the way N-tier app works by making  an own application.

I read serveral articles about it, but there’s nothing much more than a wall of text (Might I haven’t found the right place).

Although I got a tool that helps generating DAL, BLL classes but it’s just like an ‘outline’. I have no experience of working with DAL, BLL… so I could not do much.

The following is the code that made from generation tool (as I said) and slightly modified by myself.

DAL

```
Namespace FIRSTAPP.DAL
{
    class Teacher
    {
        clsOLEDB db = new clsOLEDB();

        public OleDbDataReader SelectAll()
        {
            try
            {
                db.OpenConnection();
                return db.Excute("SELECT * FROM TEACHER");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }

        }        
    public OleDbDataReader SelectRow()
        {}
   }
}
```

BLL

```
namespace FIRSTAPP.BLL
{
    class Teacher
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

        public List< Teacher > SelectAll()
        {
            DAL.Teacher dalTeacher = new DAL.Teacher();
            IDataReader dr = dalTeacher.SelectAll();

            List<Teacher> TeacherList = new List<Teacher>();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                Teacher myTeacher = new Teacher
                {
                    Id = (string)dr["Id"],
                    FullName = (string)dr["FullName"],
                    DateOfBirth = (DateTime)dr["DateOfBirth "],
                };
                TeacherList.Add(myTeacher);
            }
            dr.Close();

            return TeacherList;
        }

Public Teacher SelectRow(string TeacherId)
{}
}
}
```

DBConnector

```
namespace FIRSTAPP.DB
{
    public class clsOLEDB
    {
        string mConnectionString = @"Provider = Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = .\FirstAppDB.mdb";
        OleDbConnection mConnection;
        OleDbDataReader dataReader;
        OleDbCommand cmdCommand;

        public void OpenConnection()
        {
            mConnection = new OleDbConnection(mConnectionString);
            try
            {
                mConnection.Open();
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new Exception("Could not connect to DB");
            }
            finally
            {
                 if ( mConnection != null )
                       mConnection.Close();
            }
        }

        public OleDbDataReader Excute(string SQLText)
        { 
            cmdCommand = mConnection.CreateCommand();
            cmdCommand.CommandText = SQLText;

            try
            {
                return cmdCommand.ExecuteReader();
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new Exception("Has an error when executing");
            }
        }
public void CloseConnection()
        {
            mConnection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

My question is:

1. If we need to fetch data from data source, we have to follow these steps: Open connection -> Reading data -> Close reader -> Close connection. 
   My problem is I don’t know where do I should put Close connection statement, in BLL or DAL? How to do that? The more detail, it gets better.
2. Can you spend 1 minutes to take a look at my code. Is it clean enough? Or Does it has any another problem?

Sorry if there’re any mistakes in my English. Thank you very much.

Comment: always close your connection in finally block not in catch
and close your connection in DAL

Comment: Or better yet, use a `using` block (which essentially turns into a try-catch-finally block, but is easier to follow when reading the code).

Comment: The BLL should not be opening/closing connections to the DAL.  That's the responsibility of the DAL.  The BLL should know *nothing* about the DAL other than the methods available and the objects those methods return.

Comment: Ok, I know what you mean. But I still have to ask you that how to do that in detail?

DAL Open connection and Return a DataReader. After that, BLL reads data (DAL don't know when BLL'll be finished).

Can you give me some example, please?

Comment: I think I have an answer for myself. Thank you.